# Where to begin Spring?

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee

I have browsed Amazon for books about Spring and they are either: old (ca. 2005) or they get bad reviews. What are the best source for learning Spring in 2012? Are the books from 2005 still useful? I have been doing Java for almost 3 years now and I have tried Java EE 6 if that influences the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The books you'll find are likely to be Spring 2.5 or older; Spring 3 hasn't been out that long.

But the things you need to know for Spring 3 were there in version 2.5.  Any book will suffice if you're learning it for the first time.

I don't know what books you've seen or what the reviews have been like, but "Spring in Action" is in its 3rd edition.  It's a pretty good book.  I think "Pro Spring" is good.  Rob Harrop is one of the smart young developers at Spring Source who's been around since the beginning.  He wrote a fine book, in my opinion.

The web is the only place that has a chance to be up-to-date.

Java EE is immaterial here.

Answer (score 3):

what about the spring sources tutorials, this might be a good point to start off? http://www.springsource.org/tutorials

anyways, there seems to be alot of well written and updated documentation out there at spring source. http://www.springsource.org/get-started

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to download a [Spring Tool Suite](http://www.springsource.com/developer/sts) and create a simple project using Spring Template project wizard.

For example [here](http://www.dotkam.com/2010/04/06/spring-batch-quick-start/) is how to create a Spring Batch project using STS without writing any code at all.

---

There are also LOTS of *interactive* tutorials right from within Spring Tool Suite:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Start with the spring 3 tutorials right from the springsource websites referenced above. There are a fair amount of fundamental differences between spring 3 and 2, so don't confuse yourself by learning 2 first. Spring 3 is a better model for learning annotations. Older versions of spring required more manual configuration via xml descriptors. So you should get familiarity with using annotations heavily.